# Finding the root elements of a set of elements/nodes in a multiway tree or a connected graph

Tags: python, algorithm, linked-list, graph-theory

I have a problem finding a proper algorithm to implement the below:

I have a group of wifi links connected as a connected graph or a multiway tree.

The problem I am having is that: when I am having a disconnection, several wifi nodes are down, and I want to know what is the root problem which is the wifi node carrying all the other links

example:

- node 1 -> node 2, node 3 and node 4
- node 2-> node A, B, and C
- node 3 is a leaf
- node 4 -> node D, and E

if I have nodes 4, D, and E are down, so I know that the root cause is node 4

I thought about using least common ancestor, however, I wasn't able to adapt it to a multiway tree instead of a binary tree

Any suggestion of how to approach this?

Comment: Is this directed graph?

Comment: it is directed in a sense that we have a root, and we have a leaf. However, we can treat it as an undirected graph, as the nodes down will always be at the extremities, there is no way that root nodes are down and the leaves are up

Comment: Please post your code so far, so at least we can see the data structure. I wonder also about the `linked-list` tag... Did you use linked lists for representing the graph? Anyway, include your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to represent your wifi network, and then simply use recursion to find the problem origin:

```
d = {1: [2, 3, 4], 2: ['A', 'B', 'C'], 3: None, 4: ['D', 'E']}
def search(_d, a):
   return (_d and a in _d) or (_d and any(search(d.get(i, []), a) for i in _d))

down = ['D', 'E', 4]
r = [a for i, a in enumerate(down) if all(search(d.get(a, []), j) for j in down[:i]+down[i+1:])]
```

Output:

```
[4]
```

Edit: if it is possible that the originator of the outage is not present in `down`, you can simply flatten the structure and run the search again:

```
down = ['D', 'E']
_r = {a for c, _d in d.items() for a in [c, *([] if _d is None else _d)]}
result = [i for i in _r if all(search(d.get(i, []), j) for j in down)]
```

Output:

```
[1, 4]
```

The output is `[1, 4]`, since `4` is a child of `1`, and `4` contains the affected child nodes. It is up to you how you want to distinguish between these results, as both could be valid i.e `1` could be down or `4` could be down.

---

From your latest input, I think the best approach is to create a new dictionary, storying all the child nodes for each parent in a set.

```
from collections import defaultdict
def get_paths(_d, c = []):
   for i in _d:
     if d.get(i) is None:
        yield c+[i]
     else:
        yield from get_paths(d[i], c+[i, *([] if d[i] is None else d[i])])

result = defaultdict(list)
for a, b in d.items():
   result[a].extend(([] if b is None else get_paths(b)))

result = {a:{i for c in b for i in c} for a, b in result.items()}
```

Now, to get the down nodes:

```
def get_down(down):
   _r, _n = zip(*[[a, b] for a, b in result.items() if b and all(i in down for i in b)])
   n = {i for b in _n for i in b}
   return list(_r) + [i for i in down if i not in result and i not in n]


final_results = [get_down(i) for i in [['D', 'E','C'], ['D', 'E']]]
```

Output:

```
[[4, 'C'], [4]]
```

Comment: very interesting approach. however, if only D and E are down, the problem is most probably from 4, but it is returning an empty string where it should return 4. I believe we have to modify somehow

Comment: @BusyBee I suggest flattening `d` to find all input nodes, and then iterating over the results of the flattening to find the items that contain the affected child nodes. Please see my recent edit, as I added a potential way to solve this problem.

Comment: This is very good, however, in this case 4 should be the cause not 1 as if 1 is having issues, 4 would also be down. Currently, only 1 issue remains, if we add 'C' to the down sites, we will be now having 2 distinct fault points: 'C and '4'. In the above code, if the down sites are ['D', 'E','C'],  it will return [1], however, it should return ['C',4]